# Suppose $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb R$, $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)f'(x)\leq2$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. What is the maximum value of $f(4)$

Tags: analysis

I have assumed that the greatest value for $f(4)$ is obtained when $f(x)\cdot f'(x)=2$. Simply integrating yields the solution $f(x)=2\sqrt x$, so $f(4)=4$. This solution is technically not good enough since $f'(x)=x^{-\frac12}$ is undefined at $x=0$ and is therefore not continuous on all of $\mathbb R$, and I don't know if the largest possible value of $f(4)$ is actually $4$. Furthermore, I got pretty much totally stuck trying to reach a contradiction to prove the statement. I'm trying to apply MVT but with no avail.

Comment: why would the maximum value be at $f(x)f'(x) = 2$?

Comment: We know that $f$ is continuously differentiable, so $f'$ is continuous, so $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ isn't good example.

Comment: @user2520938: Intuitively speaking, $f'(x)=2/f(x)$ is the biggest $f'$ could be, which should produce the biggest possible $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f\,f'\le2$ is equivalent to $(f^2)'\le4$. Now
$$
f(4)^2=f^2(0)+\int_0^4(f^2(t))'\,dt\le16\implies f(4)\le4.
$$
As noted by agha $\sqrt x$ is not $C^1$. Considering $f_\epsilon(x)=2(\sqrt{\epsilon^2+x}-\epsilon)$ ($\epsilon>0$, $x\ge0$, $f_\epsilon$ defined for $x<0$ so that it is $C^1$) we see that the suprmum of the posible values of $f(4)$ is $4$.

Comment: is there an easy way to construct the negative part of $f_\epsilon(x)$ so that the function is continuously differentiable? And also since the value of 4 is only reached via a supremum, technically no function actually has $f(4)=4$, so what is the maximum value that is actually reached? Arbitrarily close to 4?

Comment: All you need is $f_\epsilon(0)=0$ and $f'_\epsilon(0)=1/\epsilon$. You can take $f_\epsilon(x)=x/\epsilon$ for $x\le 0$.